# Cannot view MySQL data from table

Tags: mysql

I've tried numerous possible things that I've Google but still viewing contents of table is not working. I even try to give root all privileges but still no effect. Just like magicarp's splash.

Error Message:

> #1356 - View 'dbname.vw_access_rights' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

Tried Query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `test_view` AS select `vw_access_rights`.`Menu_ID` AS `x`,`vw_access_rights`.`Menu_Name` AS `y` from `vw_access_rights`
```

Comment: Did you select the correct database?
Run `SHOW databases;` and then `USE database_name;`

Comment: i did.. i just replaced it with dbname.. thank you for the concern

Comment: Error says: Invalid table(s), can you run `show tables;`
and then a simple `SELECT * FROM Table_name;` query

Comment: I did tried `SELECT * FROM 'vw_check_master'` but still same error.

Comment: Replace  single quotes **'** with back ticks **`**  in  'vw_check_master'

Comment: This also should be done **'dbname.vw_access_rights'**